# binding plugin to ajax call

Tags: jquery

I take categories from another page with an ajax call. The problem is, data taken from another page needs to be part of another of an event; tabs plugin.

I get the following error with this code.

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var CategoryName = $(this).find('CategoryName');
            });
        }
    }).live('click', function() {
                $("div.row-title").tabs("div.redpanes > div");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CategoryName is a string, not a jQuery object.

```
var CategoryName = $(this).find('CategoryName').text();
```

find aint going to work!

You're probably looking for:

```
        $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var CategoryName = $(this).find('CategoryName');
            $("<div class='tab fleft'><a href='http://www.refinethetaste.com/FLPM/content/home/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewVideos&CATEGORYID="+ id +"'>"+ CategoryName.text() + "</a></div>").appendTo("#VCategories");
        CategoryName.find("div.row-title .red").tabs("div.panes > div");

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`CategoryName` is a string, not a DOM element. You can not run `find()` on it.